# How to set Default GCP resource location programmatically using fiebase cli or any other way

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I need to deploy firebase cloud functions programmatically
What I am doing. I have firebase cli install on ubuntu and have written bash script. I create a firebase project then initialize my database and firebase functions.
I attach billing account using gcloud cli.
I am doing all things from firebase cli and do want any things from console.

After all this steps i ran a command `firebase deploy --only functions`
Then there is a error
**Cloud resource location is not set for this project but scheduled functions requires it.**

When I set from console the above command runs successfully.
I set location as shown in the image
[image: Set Default GCP resource location]

Please let us know how I can **Default GCP resource location** through firebase cli?

Comment: I had a quick look into this for you and I think it's not possible. There are environment settings with the Google Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) that effect this behavior (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute#set_default_zone_and_region_in_your_local_client) and I learned researching this question that there's a way to set these values for Compute Engine using the Metadata Server (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region) but this only applies to VMs.

Comment: If the resource location is set, [projects:get](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/get) includes `resources.locationId` and it's possible (but I've not tried) that you could PATCH this value using [projects:patch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/patch)

Comment: Are you referring to Gcloud or firebase cli?
I will try my self if you share commands

Comment: I think it's not possible with Firebase CLI. With Cloud SDK (`gcloud`), it's possible to e.g. `gcloud config set compute/[region|zone]` ([link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set#compute)) but the effect of this is client-side and only applicable to, in that case, Compute Engine. There's nothing for Firebase. The only (!?) alternative would be to make a REST call against the Firebase API, `PATCH`ing the service's values but I've not tried it and it may not work.

Comment: Let me try the firebase API `Patch` call. I will try this and let you know. Can you please tell me the details of `Patching` the service's value?

Comment: @aqiltariq65 - I think you should raise this as Feature Request or Bug on [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report)